# Is initializing every variable in an array to '0' the same as initializing all of them to null?

Tags: c++, arrays, null, initialization, zero

I have been learning about using null-terminators in C++ arrays and I have been wondering if initializing an array to `0` is the same as initializing it to null.

For example:

```
char setOfCharacters [15] = {'\0'};
```

compared to

```
char setOfCharacters [15] = {0};
```

I know that initializing setOfCharacters to 0 means that every memory location in the array holds a 0 to start out with. Does initializing it to a null accomplish the same thing?

Comment: "*But why doesn't the same work for when you initialize an array to a null terminator?*" Who says that it doesn't?

Comment: Then both should behave the same. You need a [mcve].

Comment: Puzzled. In this case `'\0'`  and `0` should result in the same thing. Demo: https://ideone.com/g5h4DF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact this initialization

```
char setOfCharacters [15] = {0};
```

is equivalent to

```
char setOfCharacters [15] = { (char )0};
```

setting 0 to an object of the type char can be also written using character literal `'\0'`.

And the result of both initializations

```
char setOfCharacters [15] = {'\0'};
```

and

```
char setOfCharacters [15] = {0};
```

is that all other elements of the array that were not explicitly initialized will be zero initialized.

Take into account that the comparison

```
'\0' == 0
```

always yields `true`. The character literal in this comparison is promoted to the type `int` (in C character constants even have the type `int`, so `'\0'` is 100% equivalent to `0` there).